# wget only works for some users

Tags: connection, timeout, networking, users, wget

Currently have a strange situation: `wget` only works for one user on a system -- and root isn't it.

There are three user accounts, user A, B and root. User A can use `wget` with no problems. User B and root receive connection timeouts with `wget`. This results in similar problems with `apt-get` -- user A can successfully install updates, while user B and root get timeouts when the files are initially downloaded.

Any ideas? This is a Ubuntu system. No firewalls enabled.

Comment: Wait, how can user A install updates if they aren't root?  Are you using sudo or su to give them permissions or have you done something else?

Comment: @kaerast In this case, apt-get is being used to get the source of ntp: `apt-get source ntp`. This is not an operation which requires `root`.

Comment: @kaerast The interesting thing is that if the above command is run with `sudo` it results in timeouts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it's proxies - proxies are configured in the environment, so might be different for different users, but be consistently set up for those users by their login scripts.

I'd suggest `env | grep proxy` to find out what is set.

Comment: Genius. I was unaware of how proxies were set in Linux -- it never even apparent to me that it was possibly a proxy.